# In MongoDB version 7.0, a role created with only the 'find' permission can perform drop and write operations. How can I prevent this?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-compass, mongodb-replica-set

I'm using MongoDB Community version 7.0. The problem is, a user to whom I've only granted the 'read' permission can drop collections and perform write operations. I can't understand exactly where the problem is occurring. Has anyone encountered this?

Below are the steps I follow when creating a user.

```
use admin
db.createRole({
   role: "findRole",
   privileges: [
     { resource: { db: "example", collection: "" }, actions: ["find"] }
   ],
   roles: []
})

db.createUser({user: 'emre', pwd: 'password123', roles: [{role: 'findRole', db: 'example'}]})
```

After defining the user, I log in with MongoDB Compass. When I run the 'db.test.drop()' command, it is able to drop the collection.
I'm waiting for your assistance

I tried to create a read-only user in MongoDB, but the user I created can still perform write operations. I want to resolve this issue.

Comment: Try running the database command "connectionStatus". It is possible that the session is logged in with more than one account.

Comment: It gave the output as follows, I can't see which user it is.                                                
     `{
  authInfo: {
    authenticatedUsers: [ [Object] ],
    authenticatedUserRoles: [ [Object] ],
    authenticatedUserPrivileges: [ [Object] ]
  },
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp({ t: 1707675666, i: 2 }),
    signature: {
      hash: Binary.createFromBase64("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=", 0),
      keyId: Long("0")
    }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp({ t: 1707675666, i: 2 })`

Comment: That looks like stringify stopped after 1 or 2 levels.  If that is the mongosh shell, try running `config.set("inspectDepth",Infinity)` before running the connectionStatus command.

Comment: This is the output: `{"authInfo":{"authenticatedUsers":[{"user":"emre","db":"admin"}],"authenticatedUserRoles":[{"role":"readFind","db":"admin"}],"authenticatedUserPrivileges":[{"resource":{"db":"example","collection":""},"actions":["changeStream","collStats","dbHash","dbStats","find","killCursors","listCollections","listIndexes","listSearchIndexes","planCacheRead"]}]},"ok":1,"$clusterTime":{"clusterTime":{"$timestamp":"7334414895741403156"},"signature":{"hash":"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=","keyId":{"low":0,"high":0,"unsigned":false}}},"operationTime":{"$timestamp":"7334414895741403156"}}
`

Comment: From that same shell, try running `db.adminCommand("getCmdLineOpts")`, if auth is enabled, that should fail, if it succeeds, you will see the config option used by the mongod.

Comment: I've previously run this command and viewed that the authentication parameter is enabled. The output is as follows.   `security: {
      authorization: enabled,
      keyFile: /var/lib/mongodb/mongo-security/keyfile.txt,
      transitionToAuth: true
    }`

Comment: Was that from the same shell as the above connectionStatus output?

Comment: yes, same shell. As a client, I connect via mongodb compass.

Comment: Remove `transitionToAuth` from the config and restart, then try again.

Comment: When I remove this parameter, the members in the replica set cannot establish a connection. `mongodb-Replication [direct: primary] admin> rs.status()
MongoServerError: Command replSetGetStatus requires authentication`

Comment: transitionToAuth makes the mongod treat unauthenticated connections as authenticated.   You will need to use the same keyfile on all replica set members so they can authenticate to each other, and then remove transitionToAuth.

Comment: @Joe you can logged in only with one account. When you use `auth()`, then the former authentication is dropped. As far as I remember, MongoDB removed this strange behavior in version 4.x

Comment: You are authenticated as `emre`. Did you create an admin user as advised in my answer? Did you follow https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-with-keyfile-access-control/

Comment: I already have a user with the userAdminAnyDatabase role. Do I need to recreate it? The reason why I authenticate with the Emre role is that I want to use this user with the read-only role, but it acts as a superuser.

Comment: It is used with the same pleasure by all members, there is no problem arising from this. @Joe

Comment: You must remove `security.transitionToAuth: true`. This is used only temporarily when you like to enable authentication without downtime, see [Update Replica Set to Keyfile Authentication (No Downtime)](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/enforce-keyfile-access-control-in-existing-replica-set-without-downtime/): "*A `mongod` running with `--transitionToAuth` accepts both authenticated and non-authenticated connections. Clients connected to the `mongod` during this transition state can perform read, write, and administrative operations on any database.*"

Comment: Hello, I closed this parameter hours ago as per the instructions from my colleague Joe and you. However, I was getting a "Command requires authentication" error when connecting to the mongosh CLI because I wasn't connecting with any user. Now, following your advice, I've closed the parameter again, and I connected to the mongosh CLI on this server with the root user I created.

Comment: Currently, there doesn't seem to be any issue, and all users can perform operations within their permissions. Thank you for your support,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, did you enable [authentication](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/authentication/)? By default it is disabled.

To enable authentication you need three steps:

1. Set parameter `security.authorization: enabled`
2. Restart the `mongod` service
3. Create an admin user, i.e. a user with role `root` or `userAdminAnyDatabase`

Second, you executed `use admin`, thus role `findRole` is scoped to `admin` database. You must grant

```
roles: [{role: 'findRole', db: 'admin'}]
```

Instead of creating user-defined role, you can also grant the [built-in](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/built-in-roles/) role:

```
roles: [{role: 'read', db: 'example'}]
```

Which is (more or less) the same.

Comment: When I first noticed the issue, the authentication parameter was not set. Later, I enabled the parameter, but my problem wasn't resolved. Even when using the built-in read role, I can still perform write actions. The current parameters are as follows
```
`security:
   authorization: enabled
   keyFile: /var/lib/mongodb/mongo-security/keyfile.txt
   transitionToAuth: true
`
```

Comment: @emreyanik The `keyFile` is only needed in a replica set / sharded cluster. `transitionToAuth` is not needed either. Please see my update.

Comment: I have a replicaset.